# Send string to client upon command JAVA

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

So I am trying to have a sever sit and listen waiting for a connection from a client. The client sends over some string and the sever does some action based on whats received. Now what I would like to happen is the client sends over some command asking for data back and have the server get what it needs to and send the string back.

Not a big deal right? Well for some reason I can't get it working, my best guess is that its not closing the socket properly. I can't figure out why it wouldn't or what I am doing wrong.

Client

```
String data = "";

    DataOutputStream outToServer = null;
    BufferedReader input;

    try {
        outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());         
        outToServer.writeBytes("GETDATA");
        outToServer.flush();


      input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
      data = input.readLine();
      Log.d("ANSWER: ",  data);
      input.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Error: ", e.toString());


    }
```

Server

```
ServerSocket listeningSocket = new ServerSocket(9008);
        BufferedReader fromClient ;
        PrintStream os;


        while(true) {
            Socket clientSocket = listeningSocket.accept();
            ServerConnection clientConnection = new ServerConnection(clientSocket);
            os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            fromClient= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            if(fromClient.readLine().equals("GETDATA")){
                os.println("DATA");
                os.flush();
                clientSocket.wait();
                clientSocket.close();
            }
            else{
            clientConnection.run();
            }
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the problem, what happend when you run the code

Comment: what is the ServerConnection

Comment: Nothing happens, it doesn't log anything, success or exception.

Answer (score 0):

here is your error

```
  outToServer.writeBytes("GETDATA");
```

the right code is

```
  outToServer.writeBytes("GETDATA\n");
```

as your using  readline you should send a full line with line break